# Angular migration v13 to v14 using @angular-builders/custom-webpack

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We recently migrated Angular from version 13 to 14.

My dev dependencies and global cli both are v14.0 and we are using

"**@angular-builders/custom-webpack**" (latest **version 13.1.0**) npm package

While building the project I am getting the following error.

[image]

I don't find anything wrong with my cli version installed in dev dependencies and global cli.

[image]

NOTE:
I am guessing **@angular-builders/custom-webpack** is causing the problem **but not sure** because according to their guidelines they are supported till Angular v13. Maybe I need to wait for them to update the package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack

Comment: How did you upgrade? What commands did you run?

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/1219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will sum up the thread mentioned in [@R. Richards' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72545474/angular-migration-v13-to-v14/72559495#comment128158168_72545474).

[Author](https://github.com/just-jeb) of [@angular-builders](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders) is currently working on v14 support, PR link:

- https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/pull/1220

To temporarily fix the problem, you can delete this folder:

- node_modules\ @angular-builders\custom-webpack\node_modules

If using yarn plug and play:

- You can work it around with Yarn resolutions, but highly recommemded to wait for the official release of v14 compatible version.